# javascript scope issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

Code snippet as follows:

```
$(this).parents('td:first').next().find('option').customizeMenu('myMenu2');
```

This works,but :

```
var listener = function(){
 $(this).parents('td:first').next().find('option').customizeMenu('myMenu2');
};
listener();
```

is not working,why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

'this' does not point to the same object when put in a function, it points to the current function (in your case 'listener'). Take it as a parameter instead, if that is an option (it depends on how you call your function).

```
var listener = function(obj){
 $(obj).parents('td:first').next().find('option').customizeMenu('myMenu2');
};

listener(this);
```

Answer (score 3):

`this` is the function.  Try:

```
var listener = function(element){
  $(element).parents('td:first').next().find('option').customizeMenu('myMenu2');
};
listener(this);
```